# Is there a hyperledger fabric Ctx.stub.putStateList() method or putState for multiple states

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am new to the latest Hyperledger fabric 2. Before deprecating fabric-composer (a very well thought and intuitive framework) if you wanted to add multiple assests you could call AssetRegistry.addAll() method to add not just one asset but an array of assets. Is there an equivalent in the new hlf version 2? If I have an array of assets/states that I want added in the world-state database and I call putState() multiple times for each state/asset is it not less efficient than calling a putStateList() method that would take as param an array of states? (BTW the old naming of **asset** from the times of hyperledger composer is much more intuitive than the new name of state ... composer vs de-composer :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no putStateList in Hyperledger Fabric.

As you mentioned, the only way is to call `PutState` the number of times you want.

In terms of performance, the data to be sent by the chaincode to the peer is the same length, but I understand that if Peer node could accept a list of states, it could be more efficient on the server-side.

If we look at the internals of Node.JS library, we can see that handlePutState connects to the peer and waits:
[image]

And then, it will send the message to the peer, writing the msg to the stream:

[image]